# Trying to output all index values if they're found

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a homework assignment that I'm pretty much done with except for one part. This part of my homework asks me to generate an array with 10 random values that are in between 15 and 20, then ask the user to input an integer and search the array for that integer. If the integer (and any duplicates of the integer) is found, the index value(s) of the integer should be outputted. If the integer is not found, the text "Integer was not found" should be outputted instead.

OK, so I'm done with literally everything except the part where I'm supposed to output whether or not the integer was found.

My block of code looks like this:

..............................................................................

```
search=0;
cout<<endl<<"Enter an integer to search for in the array: "<<endl;
cin>>search;
cout<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     if(search == array[i])
     {
     cout<<"Integer "<<search<<" was found at location "<<i+1<<"."<<endl;
     }

     else
     {
     cout<<"Integer "<<search<<" was not found."<<endl;
     }
}        
break;
```

..............................................................................

The way I have this setup doesn't meet the requirements for the assignment.

Say that my randomly generated array is this string of numbers -

[16] [18] [16] [20] [19] [15] [15] [20] [19] [16]

**If I input "16" as the integer I want to search for, the output will be-**

*"Integer 16 was found at location 1"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was found at location 3"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was not found"*

*"Integer 16 was found at location 10"*

**If I input an integer that isn't in the array, the output will repeat 10 times.**

**I want to change this so that if I input "16," I just get-**

*"Integer 16 was found at location 1"*

*"Integer 16 was found at location 3"*

*"Integer 16 was found at location 10"*

**And if I input an integer that isn't on the array, I just want-**

*"Integer (x) was not found"*

Sorry if this is really simple, this is my first StackOverflow question and my first programming class, and the professor "teaches" entirely with cookie cutter youtube videos. I haven't even heard his voice yet lmao.

Thanks in advance for any help. If you need me to provide more info, let me know.

Comment: 1. Remove the third `cout` from your code. 2. Declare and intiailize a variable `bool is_found = false;` before the `for` loop. 3. In the `for` loop, if the number is found, set `is_found = true` (after or before the `cout << ... was found ...;`). 4. After the `for` loop, add `if (is_found == false) { std::cout << "Integer (x) was found\n"; }`.

Comment: Hi, please do not blame your professor. Do you have TAs or office hours to go to? Anyways, a easy thing you can do is: have a flag indicating whether if any location was found. In the loop, only output if found. And if found, also set that flag indicating something has been found. At the end, using the flag, if nothing was found, output accordingly. Good luck.

Comment: Also, what's that `break` doing outside of the loop? And you're missing the type declaration for `search`?

Comment: the break is there for the gui to return to a main menu where a user selects some options, search being one of the options, and I forgot to declare search in the example I posted. Also, I know my professor isnt really to blame, I was just frustrated. I had spent the past 4 hours trying to figure out this one simple thing lol.

Answer (score 1):

> No need for that "break" statement. What you want to do is check if
>   the number is there in the randomly generated array. If it is
>   available then you need to turn on the "found_flag". When the "for
>   loop" ends and still the "found_flag" is off that means the number you
>   are searching for is not there.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  int search;
  bool found_flag = false;
  cout<<endl<<"Enter an integer to search for in the array: "<<endl;
  cin>>search;
  cout<<endl;

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  { 
    if(search == array[i])
    {
     cout<<"Integer "<<search<<" was found at location "<<i+1<<"."<<endl;
     found_flag = true;
    }
 }

  if(!found_flag)  cout<<"Integer "<<search<<" was not found."<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this is a beginner assignment for school, I think it would've been better to have OP code it themselves, rather than giving the answer right away.

Comment: using `1` and `0` for boolean values is a bit backwards, the whole point of `bool` is that you can write `true` and `false` instead

Comment: Thanks Aditya Ishan! That seems to have done the trick. I tried Booleans earlier but I didn't use them in that way, I'll be sure to revisit those and see where my approach was wrong.